# Is there a way to render dynamic component inside the string text

Tags: reactjs

## React Placeholder

The string text that will contain a placeholder for the link element to be placed: such as `Please Click {0} to enter new Page`.
And the {0} will be replace with the Link element

**Expected result:**

Let say inside we want a clickable link (It can be other things/elements)

```html
    Please Click here <a href="https://somenewpage.com"> HERE </a> to enter new Page
```

> The reason to do this is to support multi language because the position of placeholder could change to be in other position ( E.g. โปรดกดตรง {0} )

- Workaround is to use **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** **props** and the **text to be html** which is what I did not wanted.
- Another way that I could think of is to split the text by creating a util to return the JSX Element by first using the regex pattern to identify the placeholder {/d} then append the desired element accordingly.

> I just wonder is there any other ways to do this cleanly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is, create a new component `HyperLink` and call it with two props.

```
class Hyperlink extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <a href={this.props.link}>{this.props.text}</h2>;
  }
}
```

Then call `Hyperlink` as follow

```
Please Click <Hyperlink link={href} text="HERE"/> to enter new Page
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not satisfy the expected result:
What is the steps of extracting the placeholder {0}: